# How can I send a Django Template with Context Variables to an Ajax Call?

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates

How can I send a Django template to an ajax request and include context variables for that template?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `render` for this:

```
def some_ajax_view(request):
    do_stuff()
    ...
    context = {'some_template_variable':'foo'}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html, context)
```

Now you can access the template in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({   
    ...
    success: function(response, status, XHR) {
        console.log(response); // this will print the entire html template
        $('#some-element').append(response); // this will insert the template into "some-element"
    });
```

If you need to access context variables in your ajax success callback, you can use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_ajax_view(request):
    do_stuff()
    ...
    context = {'some_template_variable':'foo'}
    html = render_to_string('some_template.html', context)
    print(html) # this will print the entire html template
    return JsonResponse({'html':html, 'context'})
```

### Edit

If you are making a `POST` request, you need to add a csrf token when the page is initially loaded (**not** from the ajax view):

```
def initial_view(request):
    do_stuff()
    return render(request, 'initial_template.html', context)
```

Now on `initial_template.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
```

Then, in your ajax call, you need to include it in the request body:

```
$.ajax({   
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.csrf_token,
    some_other_data: 'foo',
    ...
  },
  success: function(response, status, XHR) {
  ...

  });
```

Comment: How can i include csrf token?. I get this error: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect